# Как отправить HTTP запрос из Android-приложения?

Tags: java, android

Что не так с этим кодом?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

...

URL url = new URL(e.getText().toString());
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Если закомментировать последнюю строку, то ничего не происходит. Если же её оставить, то приложение компилируется, но во время выполнения выскакивает сообщение

```
В приложении "ХХХ" произошла ошибка
```

и оно аварийно закрывается.

Comment: `В приложении "ХХХ" произошла ошибка` - А сама ошибка есть?

Comment: @DanielShatz кроме указанного текста ничего не выводилось, но благодаря Вашему ответу (в частности, `AsyncTask`) проблему удалось решить, спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запрос отправляется при вызове `getInputStream();`

Скорее всего, ошибка, которую вы видите говорит вам о том, что вы делаете HTTP запрос в главном потоке Android приложения (если это не так, дополните вопрос).

Интернет запросам свойственно занимать много времени, а главный поток предназначен прежде всего для обработки и отображения пользовательского интерфейса, который должен реагировать на действия пользователя быстро.
Поэтому, необходимо создать новый поток:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    //Ваш код для запроса
  }
}).start();
```

Или, вы можете использовать `AsyncTask`. Подробнее о нем и вообще о потоках тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/124484/

*Учтите, что Вы не сможете ничего делать с элементами интерфейса не из главного потока.* Для того, чтобы выполнить код в главном потоке, используйте [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).